# Slow Magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2, varnish, redis

Good evening, my site is https://www.emporiobit.com.br it is not yet in production.
I use magento 2.2.5 with varnish and redis
I configured 4G for Varnish and 4G for php memory_limit, my VPS has 12gb ram
When I open the site there is a slow but when the site is open it loads everything at once, I believe because of the cache
The ping from Brazil where my public is located until the server is around 220~290ms, using cloudflare is around 130~140ms
I took a test at www.webpagetest.org and the TTFB scored 2,502s, I think it's a bit high
Could you help me sort out how slow to open?
[image: Report site webpagetest]

Comment: your first bit response time it 2.502 second  means your application has some issue for this  reason,it is taking  at time

Comment: 2,502s basically says "cache me". How did you configure Varnish? Have you selected "Varnish Cache" in admin settings? Have you applied the Varnish software to the server *and* Magento VCL file for it? Finally, make sure that you have enabled caches via `bin/magento cache:enable`

Comment: @AmitBera The TTFB is high, how to diagnose to achieve a better performance?
I generated a report in csv of the magento profile but I could not find out where the problem is

Comment: @DanielV.varnish is running with 4G ram and as for vcl I exported it from console admin magento2

Answer (score 2):

You can follow some steps below :

- Merge Css
- Merge javascript
- Put store to production mode
- Enable all cache

Then check speed of your store

Good luck !

Comment: Hi, all these procedures were done.

Comment: Your store still slow or speed up ?

Answer (score 0):

All related items are OK except for PHP-FPM that I do not have installed.
With this php-fpm is there performance gain?

Comment: yes and no, you need to test it, probably you have some issues with php code in your templates

Answer (score -1):

Use the latest Magento 2.2* supports php 7.1 or not.
Please below link Refere and check PHP 7.1 Support or not.

==> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/php-ubuntu.html

==> After It it is supported then you install this PHP plugin.

sudo apt-get install php7.1 php7.1-xml php7.1-dom php7.1-intl php7.1-imap

==> If you running multiple PHP versions set 7.1 to the as default Using this command.

==>    `sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1`

Set to Developer Mode `php -f bin/magento deploy:mode:show`

php -f bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

==> Check Magento cache is enabled Or not It's FPC Not Enabled please enabled FPC cache.
Then check cache status.

php -f bin/magento cache:status

If it is not enabled (cache status of 1's)

```
php -f bin/magento cache:enable
```

then you will Enable JS/CSS bundling

Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer

==> Template Configuration

Minify HTML ==> set to Yes
Javascript Settings

Merge JS files ==> set to Yes

Enable JS Bundling ==> set to Yes

Minify JS files ==> set to Yes

CSS Configuration

Merge CSS = set to Yes
Minify CSS = set to Yes

you will Do the cache flush after every step flush the cache.

```
php -f bin/magento cache:flush
```

==>Use Redis

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential tcl8.5
sudo apt-get install make
wget http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xvzf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
made
cd utils/
sudo ./install_server.sh

Edit var/www/html/MagentoFoldername/app/etc/env.php

```
'cache' => 
  array (
    'frontend' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' => 
        array (
          'server' => '127.0.0.1',
          'database' => '0',
          'port' => '6379',
        ),
      ),
      'page_cache' => 
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' => 
        array (
          'server' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port' => '6379',
          'database' => '1',
          'compress_data' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

==> Use PHP-FPM

apt-get install php7.1-fpm
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.1-fpm
sudo service php7.1-fpm restart
sudo service apache2 restart

==>Enable opcache in PHP

Edit this file /etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini find opcache.enable

```
opcache.enable=1
```

Comment: not sure if your copy-paste related to his issues....